# Get or Have Something Done with Past Participle Verb (Participle Adjective or Passive Voice)

Tags: past-tense, adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

I am a bit confused.

Here are my examples:

I get my home cleaned every other week.

I'm having my office painted.

They had their toilet fixed.

Am I correct to think that my past participle verbs are adjectives in the past participle form? Or is this an example of the passive voice?

Comment: They are all verbs in passive clauses. Notice that a _by_ phrase can be added in each case.

Comment: Incidentally, note that it is just the subordinate clauses that are passive, not the main clauses.

Comment: All of them can be followed by an agent. That's the test. They had their toilet fixed [by a plumber]; I get my house cleaned every other week [by professional cleaners]; I'm having my office painted [by my brother-in-law]. They all imply a passive, yes.

Comment: Repetition of the point I made in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple active voice sentence, the subject does something; in a passive voice sentence, something is done by the object.

Your examples are all slightly more complex. In all of them, the subject is 'getting' or 'having' something done *by someone else*. Overall, the sentences are in the active voice, but the object of that statement is a clause in the passive voice.

For example, in the sentence "*I'm getting my home cleaned*", '*getting*' is the main verb, and '*cleaned*' is a participle used to form the passive voice construction.

Answer (score 2):

> *I get my home* [*cleaned every other week*].
>
> *I'm having my office* [*painted*].
>
> *They had their toilet* [*fixed*].

The past participles are all verbs.

Note that the main clauses here are not passive. It’s just the subordinate clauses (bracketed) that are passive.

These passive are sometimes called 'bare passives', since they lack the "be" and "get" markers.

Answer (score 2):

I add to what @BillJ said.

The examples the OP listed are [passive voice constructions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive-other-forms) as described here with similar examples:

> Other structures that have ***passive*** characteristics are the ***get-passive*** and ***get/have** something **done***:

> The windows ***got broken***. (Someone broke the windows.)

> ***He’s getting*** his hair ***[dyed]***. (Someone is [dyeing] his hair.)

> We ***had*** our wooden floors ***painted***. (Someone painted our wooden floors.)

The [get passive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive) form is *get + -ed*, and the [have something done](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-something-done) is *have + object + -ed*.

Comment: Fyi, men get their hair dyed, we probably would not say coloured.

Comment: Agreed.  I quoted that from Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's British? Because for women we sometimes say coloured but for men it struck me as quite odd. :) I think I would edit my answer and also include imaginary agents to show the passive. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, @Lambie.  In [this construction, *dyed* is indeed more common than *coloured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+his+hair+dyed%2Chad+her+hair+dyed%2Chad+his+hair+coloured%2Chad+her+hair+coloured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and this in fact applies to both genders.  I updated my answer (my) last night on this.  On the *by phrase* matter, which indeed is a good point, BillJ had already mentioned that in his comments made much earlier, and I acknowledged his contribution in my answer.